# Windows(Vista) CMD Verticle Refresh Rate

Tags: c, ascii, dos, throttling

So I'm developing oldschool ASCII games for the DOS Prompt, worth my time you ask? I'd say so, its nostalgic. Anyways since I got back into it and relearned now to access the screen memory directly and all that I've been having a lot of fun until recently when the refresh rate of my games are around 30-60Hz. I notice that on XP, Vista, and 7 the Command Prompts vert refresh looks to me to throttle around 14Hz, and when you give it constant KB input it jumps up to around 25-30Hz.

So here's the gist, I run my DOS game and its really choppy in windowed mode, when I hold the spacebar it refreshes much better. When I run it in fullscreen mode (Alt+Enter) I have no probs at all so I'm convinced that it has something to do with how the main OS (Windows) meters the emulated OS' (DOS) refresh rate.

Is there some way that I can default the DOS emulators (Command Prompt) refresh rate? Or perhapse emulate a constant KB input through the KB interrupt?

Comment: If all else fails try sending the WM_PAINT message to the DOS emulator window, probably not the best solution

Answer (score 1):

The CMD DOS-prompt emulator in recent (i.e. post-2000) Windows versions is not very accurate and has a lot of compatibility issues with old DOS software - or software that behaves like old DOS software, especially when it comes to behaviour that was defined by the hardware on a real DOS system.

You mentioned directly accessing the text-mode buffer from your code. Requiring that the display timings will be stable may be too much, even in text mode.

Have you tried using an actual DOS emulator, such as [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)?